# Phantom and/or Errant Xcode 8 Compilation Errors (Following Swift-3.0 Migration)

Tags: swift, xcode, compiler-errors, swift3, xcode8

The last 3 – 4 days of migrating from Swift 2.1 to Swift 3.0 have been an absolute doozy. With 1 remaining build-time issue griming up my sidebar, I can feel the radiating glow of greatness, as I am finally at its precipice. I just have one build error to go. Just one. Then, I'm on to amazing things.

Unlike most build errors, however, this guy isn't nested in a nice little collapsible item corresponding to a file. Oh no, this error is blunt; it's the Chris Rock of errors:

> Non-failable initializer requirement 'init' cannot be satisfied by a failable initializer ('init?')

I think to myself, "Okay, I've seen this before. This should be an easy fix." I go down my internal checklist:

1. <strike>Acknowledge error.</strike>
2. Locate source of error.

I think, "Alright, the error doesn't seem to be attached to a file. That's strange. How 'bout I open up the good old Report Navigator, and see what it has to say." I click on the error in the sidebar, and the Report Navigator opens.

To my dismay, the Activity Log reveals I actually have 2 errors. I think to myself, "Xcode 8 … so far, so good!"

Nonetheless, I inspect the presented errors, one transcript at a time. From an initial glance, it seems as though the problem is occurring during the *Compile Swift source files* task. "Okay, that makes sense," I think. I decide to investigate further by clicking … **the expand transcript button.**

Upon expansion, my mind begins to melt. I couldn't let the onslaught of ludicrously-long intermediate build file pathnames deter me from reaching my goal. I've come too far (the sunk-cost fallacy be damned!). So I filter out the noise, and with laser-precision, focus on the names of the two problematic files:

- FontSizeListController.swift
- AppDefaults.swift

With this newfound knowledge, I take to the primary source editor to alleviate my project of the filth that is a failable initializer.

Upon opening the files, I quickly realize something much more sinister must be going on … Neither of the files contain a failable initializer! Furthermore, neither of the files even contain a regular initializer!

I tell myself, "Cool off, man. Take a few breaths, and think: back when you owned a PC, what did you have to do to fix problems?"

"Aha!" I exclaim to myself. "I simply have to defrag my hard drive!"

"No, you idiot! You have to restart Xcode."

The question becomes: should I click the *Clean* menu item first? Or wait, … should I hold option upon highlighting the item to reveal the secondary *Clean Build Folder…* item and click that? I decide to go with the latter.

Fast forward about an hour, and several "Clean, Restart, Rebuild" phases later…

I am here.

Does anyone know how to handle this troublesome issue? I can post detailed info if needed, but it really comes down to the two files listed above not being able to compile due to phantom failable `init` declarations.

As far as Build Settings go, my "Optimization Levels" are:

- Debug: None [-Onone]
- Release: Fast, Whole Module Optimization [-O -whole-module-optimization]

That's all I've got. Any tips or tricks to help me ride into the sunset would be greatly appreciated.

---

**Update**

The following is one of the two errors I'm receiving in its entirety (Note: A few names were changed to protect the innocent). The other error is identical, barring the filename.

> CompileSwift normal x86_64
>   /Developer/Projects/MyApp/MyApp/FontSizeListController.swift
>       cd /Developer/Projects/MyApp
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift
>   -frontend -c -filelist /var/folders/n6/05vxccjj76x7yrspfnx0yvz00000gq/T/sources-6fdc05
>   -primary-file /Developer/Projects/MyApp/MyApp/FontSizeListController.swift -target
>   x86_64-apple-macosx10.11 -enable-objc-interop -sdk
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk
>   -I /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-frexzawmtqrtdxglsieqxmvznfyw/Build/Products/Debug
>   -F /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-frexzawmtqrtdxglsieqxmvznfyw/Build/Products/Debug
>   -enable-testing -g -module-cache-path /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -D DEBUG
>   -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -I/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-frexzawmtqrtdxglsieqxmvznfyw/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug/MyApp.build/swift-overrides.hmap
>   -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-frexzawmtqrtdxglsieqxmvznfyw/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug/MyApp.build/MyApp-generated-files.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-frexzawmtqrtdxglsieqxmvznfyw/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug/MyApp.build/MyApp-own-target-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-frexzawmtqrtdxglsieqxmvznfyw/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug/MyApp.build/MyApp-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-frexzawmtqrtdxglsieqxmvznfyw/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/all-product-headers.yaml
>   -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-frexzawmtqrtdxglsieqxmvznfyw/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug/MyApp.build/MyApp-project-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-frexzawmtqrtdxglsieqxmvznfyw/Build/Products/Debug/include
>   -Xcc -I/Developer/Projects/MyApp/Result.framework/Headers -Xcc -I/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-frexzawmtqrtdxglsieqxmvznfyw/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug/MyApp.build/DerivedSources/x86_64
>   -Xcc -I/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-frexzawmtqrtdxglsieqxmvznfyw/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug/MyApp.build/DerivedSources
>   -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -working-directory/Developer/Projects/MyApp -emit-module-doc-path /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-frexzawmtqrtdxglsieqxmvznfyw/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FontSizeListController~partial.swiftdoc
>   -Onone -module-name MyApp -emit-module-path /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-frexzawmtqrtdxglsieqxmvznfyw/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FontSizeListController~partial.swiftmodule
>   -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-frexzawmtqrtdxglsieqxmvznfyw/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FontSizeListController.dia
>   -emit-dependencies-path /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-frexzawmtqrtdxglsieqxmvznfyw/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FontSizeListController.d
>   -emit-reference-dependencies-path /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-frexzawmtqrtdxglsieqxmvznfyw/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FontSizeListController.swiftdeps
>   -o /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-frexzawmtqrtdxglsieqxmvznfyw/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FontSizeListController.o
>
> :0: error: non-failable initializer requirement 'init' cannot
>   be satisfied by a failable initializer ('init?')

Comment: The full compiler error message from the Report navigator might be helpful.

Comment: @MartinR: Here ya go: `<unknown>:0: error: non-failable initializer requirement 'init' cannot be satisfied by a failable initializer ('init?')`

Comment: Then probably the only approach is to isolate the problem by removing code until the error goes away, and then adding code again. I am aware that this is not trivial in a larger project, but without seeing a self-contained, reproducible example it is difficult to help.

Comment: "neither of the files even contain a regular initializer". Have you actually tried adding one? We had this problem in the past, that the compiler "made up" a failable initializer instead of using the ancestor non-failable. Not sure how we summoned up such spooky decision, but declaring an explicit non-failable has fixed it.

Comment: Having the _exact_ same, _**frustrating**_ experience with Xcode.